# spinning button in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview

I have to create a table that has a spinning button in every cell.

Here is my CustomCell class animation method

```
- (void)animateButton {
__block CustomCell *block_button = self;
void (^animationBlock)(void) = ^(void) {
block_button.downloadBackButton.transform = 
    CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 2/3);
};

[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 
                      delay:0.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:animationBlock 
                 completion:nil];}
```

And my CustomTableViewController cellForRowAtIndexPath: method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

FAMasterTableCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (CustomCell *) [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
    [cell animateButton];
return cell;
```

}

The problem is that the table view is jerky on iPod, but runs ok on iPhone 4s.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the animation already associated with a cell instead of adding a new animation everytime?

```
FAMasterTableCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (CustomCell *) [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    [cell animateButton];
}
return cell;
```

You might also want to consider using CAAnimations instead of using UIView animations. I believe animating the layer instead of the view would increase the performance.

Comment: UIView animations should not be much slower than direct CABasicAnimations. UIViews are merely lightweight wrappers around CALayers, and I've noticed a negligible performance difference in the animation of one vs. the other in my benchmarks, even on the oldest iOS hardware.

Comment: Very good information, I didn't realize they were just lightweight wrappers.

Comment: Yes, it's not like NSViews on the Mac, which have a lot more baggage. One of the first things I did in the beta of the iPhone SDK was look at UIView's performance, and was pretty impressed with it. I do some stuff in raw CALayers, but mostly that's for Mac / iOS cross-platform display code (like in Core Plot). UIKit was clearly built with Core Animation as one of its foundations.

Comment: Can't put it in if block. i actualy have a flag that says if animation should start or not. Like if (flag) { [cell animateButton];}